# Relative path for asset function for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 5.1 framework and I want to use asset() function in blade templates.

Problem is that my application can have different domains: http://www.domain1.com and http://www.domain2.com in development mode.

When I use correct asset() syntax, it adds full path to a file, including domain.

```
   <link href="{{ asset("/css/style.css") }}" type="text/css" />
```

converts to

```
  <link href="http://www.domain1.com/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Question is:
Is it possible to configure laravel, so it will not add full domain name. 
Expected result is:

```
<link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I thought the asset method generates a url based on the current domain?

Comment: Why don't you write directly /css/style.css  in the link?

Comment: I haven't tested but... wouldn't that mean that when you have a url like domain1.com/users/123/, it won't locate the resource because it will look for the css in path users/123/css/style.css ?

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround that I hope doesn't have any contraindications.
You could set `ASSET_URL=" "` in your `.env` file.

`ASSET_URL` contains the prefix that will be used for your `asset()` helper, when it's value is empty (it is by default) it will use your `APP_URL` instead.
Using `" "` as a prefix will make sure that all your asset paths will start from the root of any domain you are using (ex. `<link href=" /css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">`, note the space before the URL).
Using this solution you can easily switch to a CDN in the future just changing your `ASSET_URL` setting.
The bad thing is that it adds a space prefix to all asset urls, browsers ignore that but you may encounter other issues when working with javascript.

A case I could think of where this would not work is when you can access the site from different directory levels (ex. http://www.domain1.com/ and http://www.domain2.com/subpath/).

Answer (score 4):

This works for me;

```
parse_url(asset('path/to/asset'), PHP_URL_PATH)
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `asset()` and other helpers generate only full paths. You have two choices:

1. Create your [own helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade) for relative URL generating.
2. Create relative URLs manually.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the space character by setting `ASSET_URL='/.'` in the `.env` file.
That makes asset url like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/./css/app.css">`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your head:

```
<base href="/yourapp" />
```

it's quick solution!